# How do I have Java auto-update for both 32-bit and 64-bit?

Tags: 64-bit, java, 32-bit, auto-updates

I have both Java 32-bit and Java 64-bit installed on my computer, and when automatic updates rolls around it asks me to save in Program Files (x86), but no equivalent for 64-bit Java comes up. How can I get 64-bit Java to update as well as 32-bit Java?

Comment: Its very likely the service that handles this only supports 32-bit support.  One way to check is to remove the 32-bit version and see if the automatic updates still happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [**What is Java Auto Update? How do I change notify settings?**](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_update.xml) article:

> **Why is the Update tab missing from the Java Control Panel?**
>
> Java Auto Update is currently not available for 64-bit versions of Java. 64-bit versions of Java do not include the Update tab in the Java Control Panel.

Guess you'll have to do it manually. Given the sheer number of security issues with Java of late, not having auto-update support x64 is a real head-scratcher.

Comment: See [ticket #6492837](http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6492837) from year 2006. I suppose everyone in Oracle Corporation is using Windows XP and Internet Explorer 6. (*Gosh*)

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: 2006? Wow, and who knows whether that's even the first bug to deal with this. Sun/Oracle might as well just officially state that they're not interested in supporting 64-bit properly. I advise people nowadays to stay away from the Java plugin if possible, and even if it's installed most browsers restrict it by default anyway.