# How to update Java 32 & 64 bit on windows8.1?

Tags: windows, windows-8, 64-bit, java, 32-bit

My operating system is Windows 8.1 (64 bit). Avast has been complaining that the Java installed is out of date. Occasionally, a popup comes on asking to update Java (it looks legit) and I press "ok". But it doesn't seem to do anything (repeating itself every day or so). Checking the list of installed programs in my control panel I found this,

[image]

I ***think*** it means that I have both 32 and 64bit versions of Java installed. How do I update these?

A generic search finds this question - 
[How do I have Java auto-update for both 32-bit and 64-bit?](https://superuser.com/questions/555239/how-do-i-have-java-auto-update-for-both-32-bit-and-64-bit)

Which tells me that auto-update is unavailable for 64bit releases of Java. So, how do I do this manually? Should I uninstall the current Java runtime and then reinstall the new one, or can I just download the latest installer, run it and hope that it does an in-place install?

Some detailed step-by-step instructions meant for an idiot would be appreciated (if it's not asking for much).

Comment: This took my only seconds to find: http://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp download and install both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions if you want both.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Should I first remove the old version, or can I run that updater in-place?

Comment: Old versions are not removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove both the 32 and 64 bit Java installations, then go to the Java site and download the 32 bit binary and install it, you shouldn't need the 64 bit binary, so I recommend not installing that unless there is a specific reason to do so.

Comment: I think you mean normally you don't need the 64-bit one.  Firefox, Chrome, IE all are 32-bit by default.

Comment: Forgot about web browsers, I use a 64 bit Firefox nightly.

Comment: The only reason I have a 64-bit version is because someone told me that "its future-proof". I use the regular versions of all the web-browsers, so that wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Side question: on the recommendation to remove my existing JRE, does it apply to the JDK also? It sounds like a very cumbersome process to update, what should be a popular piece of software...

Comment: Burn that bridge(or cross it, whatever) when you come to it, if it doesn't update automatically then remove it and do it manually. And 64 bit isn't more future proof since 32 bit will be supported for quite a while into the future, but 64 bit will run faster, though it will use more RAM.

Comment: The JDK is Java..

Comment: Yes, but it is development kit, Avast just wants an updated runtime enviroment, so it isn't necessary to update the JDK to solve your current problem, plus the JDK by itself will also most likely be updated less often and isn't as critical for day to day computer usage.

Comment: That clears up my confusion. Thanks Slowki! :) upvoting your comment.